# Adding .jars to CLASSPATH?

Tags: jar, classpath

I'm trying to interact with the unofficial Android API: http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/ . It includes two .jars that I have to add to my classpath (I'm on Windows 7)

I've placed both .jars, androidmarket and protobuf, into my project
directory, and edited my CLASSPATH to include the two .jars:

> C:\xxxxxxxxxx\JAVA Project Folder\protobuf-java-2.2.0.jar;C:\xxxxxxxxxx\JAVA
>   Project Folder\androidmarketapi-0.6.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java
>   \jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip

However, when I create a tester class to try and instantiate a new
MarketSession object, javac refuses to compile! Here's my tester
class:

```
public class Tester {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        MarketSession session = new MarketSession(true);
            System.out.println("login...");
    }
}
```

javac complains that it can't find the MarketSession symbol. Any
clues? I know it's a specific question geared towards the API, but I imagine I'm probably missing something fundamental about .jars and the CLASSPATH. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `import` `MarketSession` in your `Tester` class

```
import com.gc.android.market.api.MarketSession;
public class Tester {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        MarketSession session = new MarketSession(true);
            System.out.println("login...");
    }
}
```